# Dart: How do I convert an array of objects to an array of hashmaps?

Tags: object, dart, hashmap, flutter

I want to convert my objects to hashmaps so I can use the Flutter method channels to send data to Android.

I've thought of iterating through and mapping them one by one, but there's got to be a more elegant way to do this...

Example:

Object

```
class Something {
  Something(this.what, this.the, this.fiddle);
  final String what;
  final int the;
  final bool fiddle;
}
```

Somewhere else

```
List<Something> listOStuff = List<Something>.generate(10, (int index){
  return Something(index.toString(), index, false,);
});

List<Map<String, dynamic>> parseToMaps(List<Something> listOStuff){
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> results;
  // do something crazy to get listOStuff into Map of primitive values for each object
  // preferably a built in method of some sort... otherwise, i guess i'll just iterate...
  // maybe even an imported package if such thing exists
  return results;
}

List<Map<String, dynamic>> listOMaps = parseToMaps(listOStuff);
```

[Something like this in Java](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-convert-object-to-map-example/)

Comment: Could you give an example of an object you are trying to convert?

Comment: Updated a simple example

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `map` and return the object that you want:

```
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> listOMaps = listOStuff
            .map((something) => {
                  "what": something.what,
                  "the": something.the,
                  "fiddle": something.fiddle,
                })
            .toList();
```

Comment: Yeah, this was the iterative / mapping approach I was talking about... but there really isn't much else I guess...

Comment: Honestly, I was looking for the answer below, but the question that I wrote fits this answer perfectly so here's my accepted to you good sir

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for, but there is a way to have custom objects encoded without having to specify it directly when you call the method.

What you have to do is implement a [MethodCodec](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/MethodCodec-class.html) and/or [MessageCodec](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/MessageCodec-class.html) that defines how your object is encoded and decoded. The easiest way is probably to subclass [StandardMethodCodec](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/StandardMethodCodec-class.html) and/or [StandardMessageCodec](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/StandardMessageCodec-class.html) (it might be enough to override StandardMessageCodec and pass it to StandardMessageCodec).

If you implement read & write correctly for your object, then all you have to do is pass the list of objects directly to your method call and flutter will handle the encoding.

Note that there are corresponding classes on the Android & iOS sides of things that you could use to have the data decoded directly to objects, and in fact you might have to implement them to get things to work depending on how you do it.

Comment: This would be perfect!  Do you have examples of how I could do this?  Possibly with the simple example I gave above?